# Uninstalled snapd from Windows 10 WSL. Now can't install anything

Tags: apt, snap, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I had installed snapd so that I could install sublime-text. Then WSL said that it can't do that yet. So I uninstalled snapd. Now I can't install anything at all because of this `Could not read response to hello message from hook` issue.

```
$ sudo apt install kate
-- largely irrelevant output removed --
E: Could not read response to hello message from hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true: Success
E: Could not read response to hello message from hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true: Success
```

I can't autoremove anything. I can't reinstall snapd. I can apt update.

Phew! aptitude still works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could trying removing the offending apt hook, like this:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20snapd.conf
```

Comment: And or make a backup first...